# Cauchy stress tensor vs Piola-Kirchoff stress tensors, when to use them?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

I'm just reading about the P-K stress tensors, while I've seen Cauchy stress tensor in a course a couple months ago. From a technical point of view, I think it's clear what they represent.

- Cauchy stress tensor gives the force on the current configuration with respect to deformed areas on the current configuration. So if $da \hat{n}$ is the infinitesimal area vector in the current configuration, the force would be $df = T (da) \hat{n}$.
- First P-K stress tensor gives the force in the current configuration but by means of the undeformed areas in the reference shape, so that $df= P (dA) \hat{N}$ (I denote with capital letters everything in the reference configuration)
- Second P-K stress tensor does the same thing of the first P-K tensor, except it gives the pull-back of the force $df$ via the deformation to which the body is subject. So if the deformation is $F$, the second P-K tensor $S$ should be such that $S (dA) \hat{N}= F^{-1} df$

Now, the question is: why do I need them? When do I use the first, when the second, when the third? I'll try to answer myself, but please tell me if I am getting this right.

The first one is pretty clear: you have a deformed body, you measure the deformation and then find the stress forces applied to it. The problem is the other two: when/how to use them?

I have not an engeenering background, so sorry if this is a trivial question but I'd really like some practical, intuitive examples. (Also, if my understanding on the definitions of the three tensors is wrong, please tell me!)

Answer (score 1):

A common use case is *Computational Solid Mechanics* (CSM).
The choice of stress measures ($P$, $T$ or $S$) depends on how you solve the mechanical equilibrium problem numerically. It all comes down to solving *partial differential equations* (PDEs) of one kind of stress tensor field.
If the PDEs are formulated in the *reference configuration*,  the *First Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor* will be a natural choice.

For example, the *FFT-based solvers* (aka spectral solvers) require  discretization of the solid material with a *regular grid* (mesh) in the *reference configuration*, where the grid points remain constant and equally-spaced. Common FFT algorithms simply do not work on a deformed grid, so it is impossible to use the current (deformed) configuration.

Therefore, you will see the mechanical equilibrium equation like:
$$\mathbf \nabla \cdot P = 0$$
in every article of spectral solvers, where $\mathbf{P}$ is the first Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensor. Please refer to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08893.pdf) for deeper understanding of the FFT methods in CSM.
During simulation, the spectral solver calls the [constitutive subroutine](https://github.com/eisenforschung/DAMASK/blob/85b788f1c52a1a018463a36aed780295ba157e16/src/grid/grid_mech_spectral_basic.f90#L240) to calculate   $\mathbf{P}$ at each grid point in the reference configuration at every time step and applies forward and backward FFT to $\mathbf{P}$.

In theoretical *constitutive models*, there are numerous scenarios where you need to formulate the constitutive equations in the reference configuration, using the first or second Piola-Kirchhoff stress tensors. I would quote [another answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/11207/38940) here:

> It doesn't really make sense to talk about a measure of stress in isolation, without also considering how to measure strain, and how to model the constitutive equations that give the relationship between stress and strain.

> For example 2-PK stress works nicely with Green strain, which is a convenient way to define the behavior of a body which has "small" elastic deformations superimposed on arbitrary large rigid body motions - in particular, large rigid body rotations, where approximations like $\sin\theta \approx \theta$
> are not appropriate.